# F# WebRequest throws WebException ("protocol error") instead of 404 status code

Tags: f#, httpwebrequest, riak

I'm implementing a F#-ish web request function which looks like this:

```
let request 
        (httpMethod:string) 
        (url:string) 
        (headers:Header list) 
        (content:Content option)=

    let groupHeaders (headers:WebHeaderCollection) =
        let d = new Dictionary<string, string list> ()
        let addToDict h =
            let oldValue = if d.ContainsKey(h) then d.Item(h) else []
            d.Item(h) <- oldValue @ [headers.Get h]

        headers.AllKeys |> Array.iter addToDict

        d |> Seq.map (|KeyValue|) |> Map.ofSeq

    async {
        let rq = WebRequest.Create(url) :?> HttpWebRequest
        rq.Method <- httpMethod

        headers 
        |> List.iter (fun (key, value) -> rq.Headers.Add(key, value) |> ignore ) 

        match content with
        | Some (contentType, bytes) ->
            rq.ContentType <- contentType
            do! rq.GetRequestStream().AsyncWrite(bytes) 
        | None -> ()

        try
            use! response = rq.AsyncGetResponse()
            let webResponse = response :?> HttpWebResponse

            let responseCode = webResponse.StatusCode

            let stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream()
            let length = webResponse.ContentLength |> int32 //TODO what if the data is bigger then 4GB?

            let! bytes = stream.AsyncRead(length)

            let respHeaders = groupHeaders webResponse.Headers
            return
                match webResponse.StatusCode with 
                | HttpStatusCode.OK -> OK (respHeaders, bytes)
                | HttpStatusCode.NotFound -> NotFound
                | otherCode -> Error <| otherCode.ToString()
        with 
            | :? WebException as ex -> 
                return Error <| ex.Status.ToString()
    }
```

The problem is that if I try to get a page (try to get a `riak` value) which returns `404` the result is a `WebException` with the message `The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.` instead of a response with `HttpStatusCode.NotFound`

Doing `curl GET` for the same URL gives me the following result:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:18098/riak/user/asfasfd?returnbody=true
* About to connect() to localhost port 18098 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 18098 (#0)
> GET /riak/user/asfasfd?returnbody=true HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.27.0
> Host: localhost:18098
> Accept: */*
>
* additional stuff not fine /usr/src/ports/curl/curl-7.27.0-1/src/curl-7.27.0/lib/transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 404 Object Not Found
< Server: MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.9.0 (someone had painted it blue)
< Date: Sun, 28 Oct 2012 05:30:12 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 10
<
not found
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Any ideas why the exception `WebException` is thrown? 
If I want to identify the 404-page not found situation, what options do I have instead of parsing the exception message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@desco is correct, but elaborating on his answer -- here's how you can use pattern matching to solve your problem:

```
try
    // Do stuff here
    //
with
| :? WebException as webEx when (webEx.Response :? HttpWebResponse) ->
    /// The exception's Response, as an HttpWebResponse.
    /// From this we can get the HTTP status code of the response.
    let httpWebResponse = webEx.Response :?> HttpWebResponse

    // Return an error message based on the HTTP status code.
    match httpWebResponse.StatusCode with
    | HttpStatusCode.NotFound ->
        return NotFound

    | otherCode ->
        return Error <| otherCode.ToString()

| :? WebException as webEx ->
        return Error <| webEx.Status.ToString()
```

Also, the reason you get the WebException is because that's how `HttpWebResponse` handles 4xx and 5xx response codes. The `match` statement in your code where you check `webResponse.StatusCode` won't ever reach the `HttpStatusCode.NotFound` case because the exception will be thrown instead. You should keep the `match` there though, to handle any non-error codes which are not `HttpStatusCode.OK` (e.g., a 301 redirect).

Comment: what if I want to match to `207` which is not an enumerated choice?  I can't figure out how to cast `207` to `HttpStatusCode` in the pattern to be matched.  I want to avoid casting `httpWebResponse.StatusCode` so I don't lose the nice names for the other codes.

Comment: @uosɐſ You can handle `207` by defining a [partial active pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) like this: `let (|MultiStatus|_|) (code : HttpStatusCode) = if int code = 207 then Some () else None`. Then, you can use that to create a new case within the `match` statement (it needs to come before the last case though, because that's a catch-all case).

Comment: @JackP. - Thanks.  How does that compare to this which I worked out since: `| code when code = enum<HttpStatusCode> 207 -> PropFindResult.Success `?

Comment: @uosɐſ They should compile to the same IL, but I prefer my version because: (1) it's reusable; and (2) it encapsulates the status code value (`207`), so the code is more readable -- you can just think in terms of what the status code *signifies* rather than it's numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

WebException has 2 properties that should help you:

1. [Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status.aspx) of type [WebExceptionStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus.aspx). 404 should be indicated by ProtocolError
2. [Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx) exposes response returned by remote host. Downcast response to HttpWebResponse and its use [Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode.aspx) property

Comment: 1. Status of WebExceptionStatus doesn't have a value for the 404 situation  2. Downcasting ex.Response to a HttpWebResponse and extract the status from there could work, with the small issue that if a real error occured ex.Response is null. Still the WebRequest class doesn't seem designed to be used like that. Is there a cleaner approach?